# "undefined method 'name' for false:FalseClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

All functional tests for my object "Line" fail. I don't even know where to start debugging this:

> 21) Error: test_should_update_line(LinesControllerTest):
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for false:FalseClass
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/decl
>   aration/static.rb:11:in`=='
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/att
>   ribute_methods/write.rb:57:in `convert_number_column_value'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/att
>   ribute_methods/write.rb:50:in`type_cast_attribute_for_write'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/att
>   ribute_methods/serialization.rb:88:in `type_cast_attribute_for_write'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/att
>   ribute_methods/write.rb:38:in`write_attribute'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/att
>   ribute_methods/dirty.rb:67:in `write_attribute'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/att
>   ribute_methods/write.rb:14:in`port='
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/attr
>   ibute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/attr
>   ibute_assigner.rb:15:in`each'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/attr
>   ibute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/attr
>   ibute_assigner.rb:14:in`tap'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/attr
>   ibute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
>       c:in`object'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/stra
>   tegy/create.rb:9:in `result'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/fact
>   ory.rb:42:in`run'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/fact
>   ory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/n
>   otifications.rb:125:in`instrument'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/fact
>   ory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/stra
>   tegy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in`block in
>   define_singular_strategy_method'
>
> ```
> c:/code/vsdb/test/functional/lines_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class: LinesControllerTest>'
> c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/c
> ```
>
> allbacks.rb:462:in `_run__987382823__setup__855471168__callbacks'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/c
>   allbacks.rb:405:in`__run_callback'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/c
>   allbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/c
>   allbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
>       c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/t
>   esting/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'

lines_controller_test.rb:

> class LinesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
>       setup do
>         @line = FactoryGirl.create(:line)
>       end
>
> ```
> test "should update line" do
>   put :update, id: @line, line: { description: @line.description }
>   assert_redirected_to line_path(assigns(:line))   
> end
> ```
>
> end

test_helper.rb:

> ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test" require
>   File.expand_path('../../config/environment', **FILE**) require
>   'rails/test_help' require 'capybara/rails'
>
> class ActiveSupport::TestCase   # Setup all fixtures in
>   test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.   #   #
>   Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in
>   integration tests   # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
>
> def setup
>       #all kinds of owners
>       @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:owner, iso:true, admin:true)
>       @iso = FactoryGirl.create(:owner, iso:true)
>       @isa = FactoryGirl.create(:owner)
>         #be admin by default
>         @controller.stubs(:current_owner).returns(@admin)
>
> ```
> #fixtures for compliance rates verification
> @art = FactoryGirl.create(:unit, name: "art", unit_code: "1110000", parent_unit_id: 1100000)   end
> ```
>
> # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here... end
>
> class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest     include Capybara::DSL
>
> def teardown        Capybara.reset_sessions!        Capybara.use_default_driver
>     end end

Comment: probably something wrong with your line factory

Comment: Can you post your factory code for `line`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing `@line` to update where you should be passing `@line.id`. Try changing that to:

```
put :update, id: @line.id, line: { description: @line.description }
```